# How to reference a resource(javascript) from a npm package in an angular/ionic application?

Tags: javascript, angular, phaser-framework

I've an Ionic blank application, in which I'm trying to use phaser(one javascript library).
I've setup my blank ionic app(Would be the same with angular I guess).

I've installer the phaser package:

`npm install phaser@3.24.1 --save`

I see the node module and it has a `dist/phaser.min.js` that I need to include.

I've made many tries, but I get 404 error for each of them:

```
<script src="../node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/@phaser/phaser.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/@phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

and many others.

If I copy this phaser.min.js directy in my asset folder it works, but that removes the usefullness of referencing a package.

How should I reference this?

Comment: Why are you adding in a script tag and not using the `import` syntax?

Comment: I found a tutorial from phaser, it's how they were doing it. I'm open to other suggestion? But I tought it was because Phaser3 was not written in typescript

Comment: Can you please share minimal reproduction on stackblitz?

Comment: It's a little cumbersome, but you can use Phaser with TypeScript [tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/07/13/phaser-3-typescript-tutorial/)